# how to debug with real device using xcode tools in terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal

I've already have Xcode tools installed on my mac and now I can build my iOS game project like this:

```
xcodebuild -scheme "Game Scheme"
```

and the next thing I want is to install and run the generated app (using the command above) on a real device (connect to mac).

I'm wondering if there is a command such as (I read the document about xcrun but still can not figure out how to get this done):

```
xcrun "my game.app" -l
```

to install the game on my device, run it, and print all the logs in my terminal just like Xcode did in the console.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doing so is a complicated process that requires reverse-engineering the MobileDevice framework interface or the underlying protocols.

Fortunately, various parties have done the work for you.

https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy

http://www.libimobiledevice.org/